# i am learning angular bootstrap, and i am trying to install npm on my machine. it is not getting installed

Tags: node.js, angular, npm-install

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpv7A.png)

I have attached the image for reference

While it showed npm funds, I removed them using set fund false --global. Then for audited packages as well, used the code --no-audit. It isn't showing any vulnerabilities, but I think it is not installed as well. What else should I do now?

Comment: Why do you think it's not installed? Does the package show up in `package.json`?

Answer (score 0):

Try these options :
Uninstalling and reinstalling cli using :

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

check the node version and also try different options for finding the version :
those are :

```
ng --version
ng version
ng v
```

Also try closing and re-opening the cli after installation and check. ( very few times it happens so ).

Thanks! Comment if you stuck still.

Answer (score 0):

***According to My Knowledge***

Clear the Cache of npm using Following:
(windows)
Open Search Bar, and Search "%Appdata%", Press Enter
then Open Local Folder in Appdata Directory,
then Search for npm-cache Folder.
Delete this Folder.

Note:
I didn't faced any issue kinda this but sometime this fixes my problems